make Primefaces p:rowEditor look like normal p:commandButton
my issue is I need to make the p:rowEditor look like a p:commandButton, because I use both in one Datatable, they are next to each other and it just looks bad. My version is 13.07.
I already tried putting the p:rowEditor in a button, but doesnt work. Of course i could write my own logic but i dont know how to access the methods that the p:rowEditor uses to make a row Editable and End the edit with a save/cancel.
<p:column style="width:1rem">
                            <p:rowEditor editTitle="Edit Row" cancelTitle="Cancel Edit" saveTitle="Save Row"/>
                        </p:column>
<p:column exportable="false" ariaHeaderText="Aktionen" style="width: 3rem;">
                            <p:commandButton action="#{...}" 
                                             icon="pi pi-trash" 
                                             style="margin-right:.5em;"
                                             process="@this"
                                             id="deleteEntryButton" 
                                             >
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{...}" target="#{...}"/>
                                <p:confirm   icon="pi pi-exclamation-triangle" />
                            </p:commandButton>

                        </p:column>

Thank you very much!

Tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles?

yep.. didnt change anything, but i can edit the style inside the html element, so if you by any chance know where to find all the command button styles, that´ll do

Just use the DOM inpsector and steal the CSS from LinkButton: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/linkButton.xhtml  And apply it to .ui-row-editor styling.

right, thank you so much <3
